# Counting inputs with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ultimately, I want to build a script that takes a user's input and not only counts how many inputs they have, but repeats them in the final statement.  The script is supposed to ask a user what they want to put into a basket.  After the user is satisfied, they can enter 'nothing' which will stop the loop and return something like "there are x items in the basket: item1, item2, item3"...etc.

I cannot figure out how to count each input and then use the exact inputs in the last line.

Here is what I have so far:

```
print('Add as many items to the basket as you want. When you are done, enter "nothing".')
print('What do you want to put into the basket now?')
while True:
    myInput = input()
    variable = 0
    if myInput == "nothing":
        print('There are' + str(variable) + ' items in the basket: [' + x + '.]')
        break
    else:
        print('Okay, what else?')
        variable += 1
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print('Add as many items to the basket as you want. When you are done, enter "nothing".')
print('What do you want to put into the basket now?')
#create basket list
basket = []
while True:
    myInput = input()
    if myInput == "nothing":
        #print length of basket to count elements, and use basket to show content
        print('There are ' + str(len(basket)) + ' items in the basket: '+ str(basket))
        break
    else:
        # add input to basket
        basket.append(myInput)
        print('Okay, what else?')
```

While quickly testing, I got an error when user input is '',
meaning they didnt put any character and pressed enter.

I'll leave that bug with you to figure out.